# React component won't re-render on props change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is the `BookList` component to re-render on the `filter.sortBy` prop change.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getBooks } from '../actions/bookActions';
import Spinner from './Spinner';
import BookItem from './BookItem';
import sortBooks from '../selectors/books';

class BookList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getBooks();
  }

  render() {
    const { books, loading } = this.props;

    let booksContent;

    if (!books || loading) {
      booksContent = <Spinner />;
    } else {
      if (books.length > 0) {
        booksContent = books.map(book => <BookItem book={book} key={book._id} />);
      } else {
        booksContent = <h4>No books found</h4>;
      }
    }

    return (
      <div className='feed'>
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-md-12'>
                            {booksContent}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

BookList.propTypes = {
  books: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.array, PropTypes.object]).isRequired,
  getBooks: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const books = sortBooks(state.books.books, state.filter.sortBy);

  return {
    books: books
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getBooks })(BookList);
```

There is another component to change the `state.filter.sortBy` value. From what got logged inside `mapStateToProps()` above `state.filter.sortBy` changes correctly.

How do I get `BookList` to re-render when I change the `sortBy` value?
The complete repo is on https://github.com/ElAnonimo/booklist
So far I've tried a `constructor()`, a `componentWillReceiveProps()`  in `BookList`.

**UPDATE.**

This is what my `sortBooks` selector looked like

```
export default (books, sortBy) => {
  return books
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (sortBy === 'title') {
        return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
      } else if (sortBy === 'releasedAt') {
        return a.releasedAt < b.releasedAt ? -1 : 1;
      }
    });
};
```

As was mentioned in the accepted answer that way the selector returned an internally modified but still the original `books` array to the `BookList` component. Which resulted in no props change for Redux.

This is how I got it to return a modified copy of the original array.

```
export default (books, sortBy) => {
  return [...books]
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (sortBy === 'title') {
        return a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1;
      } else if (sortBy === 'releasedAt') {
        return a.releasedAt < b.releasedAt ? -1 : 1;
      }
    });
};
```

The credit goes to Ryan C.

**UPDATE 2.**
Another credit to Ryan C. Thank you for sharing the wisdom.

Here are his suggested modifications applied.

`booksReducer`. Before it lacked the `SORT_BY_TITLE` and `SORT_BY_RELEASED_AT` cases.

```
import {
  GET_BOOKS,
  BOOKS_LOADING,
  DELETE_BOOK,
  SORT_BY_TITLE,
  SORT_BY_RELEASED_AT
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  books: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case BOOKS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_BOOKS:
      return {
        ...state,
        books: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case DELETE_BOOK:
      return {
        books: [...state.books.filter(book => book._id !== action.payload.id)]
      };
    case SORT_BY_TITLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        books: [...state.books.sort((a, b) => a.title < b.title ? -1 : 1 )]
      };            
    case SORT_BY_RELEASED_AT:
      return {
        ...state,
        books: [...state.books.sort((a, b) => a.releasedAt < b.releasedAt ? -1 : 1 )]
      };    
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The modification to the `BookList`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    books: state.books.books
});
```

These changes effectively leave out the need for a selector in the project.

Comment: Demo would be useful, not many people will be willing to go through github sources.

Comment: The getBook() shouldnt be in `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Did you mean `getBooks()`?

Comment: `console.log("books from selectors:", books);` this line is loggin it as empty object @ElAnonimo.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to clean up the original question.

Comment: @ElAnonimo Please see my update regarding performance concerns with this approach.

Comment: @Ryan C Acknowledged and implemented. Please take a look at the Update 2. Is it what you meant?

Comment: @ElAnonimo Yes, and then you should be able to remove the `sortBooks` call from `mapStateToProps` and the sorting still work.

Comment: @Ryan C That modification was applied too. I still need the `filterReducer` but only to display the `filter.sortBy` value in the dropdown where I change the sorting. It's the `Navbar` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your `sortBooks` method is sorting the array in place, such that the same `books` array reference is always returned (even though the order of the elements within it may have been changed). This causes react-redux to think that the properties returned by `mapStateToProps` have not changed (react-redux only does a shallow comparison). If you change `sortBooks` to first duplicate the array and then sort it and return the new array rather than mutating the existing array, it should work.

**UPDATE**
After seeing your resolution, I think it would be better to handle this sorting in your reducer since the books array is in state. This way you can control only doing the sorting in response to the action that changes the sort. The way it is now, you will end up re-rendering the book list on every state change (even if the sort did not change) since mapStateToProps will **ALWAYS** return a different books array.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you. Te redeem myself a bit I tried that before only I returned the original array in place of the copy. I'll edit the question to show what I've done.

Comment: hm, I am curious why a `Component` (i.e. not a `PureComponent`) won't re-render anyway even if it's the same array...

Comment: @Aprillion This is part of the functionality of the react-redux connect method.